# Set properties such as label color in etaremune

Tags: enumerate, etaremune

I would like to set the properties of `etaremune` the same way I could easily do with `enumitem` for `enumerate`, as the label color for instance. The code below shows an example with red-color labels in `enumerate`. What would be the easiest way to do the same for `eratemune`?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlist[enumerate]{font=\color{red}}

% What I am looking for
% \setlist[etaremune]{font=\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\section{enumerate list}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Last item
\end{enumerate}

\section{etaremune list}

\begin{etaremune}
    \item Last item
    \item Second item
    \item First item
\end{etaremune}

\end{document}
```

[image: eratemune label color setting]

Comment: Seems to me that it might be easier to define a `\newlist` with enumitem and use that instead of anohter package.

Comment: In that case, how would you define a `\newlist` with inverted enumeration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two versions that define a `ReverseEnumerate` list using the `enumitem` package that produces decreasing numerical labels as is the case with `etaremune` package:

1. A simple solution if you are willing to manually provide the number of items in the list using the `start=` option:

   ```
   \begin{ReverseEnumerate}[start=3]
       \item ...
   \end{ReverseEnumerate}
   ```
2. A more complicated version which does *not* require the `start=` option.
   To change global settings on `ReverseEnumerate`, one must use the starred variant

   ```
   \setlist*[ReverseEnumerate]{font=\color{blue}}
   ```

   to append the settings to the existing settings.  Another option is to specify the settings on a per list basis:

   ```
   \begin{ReverseEnumerate}[font=\color{orange}]
       \item ...
   \end{ReverseEnumerate}
   ```

   This second version also uses the `etoolbox` and `pgfmath`  packages. If that is an issue, it should not be difficult to be done without those packages.

Similar to the `etaremune` package, two runs are required for this to work.
Both of the following two [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) yield:

[image]

#### Code: `Simple Version`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlist{ReverseEnumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\newcommand*{\SavedValue}{0}%
\setlist[ReverseEnumerate,1]{%
    label={\arabic*\addtocounter{ReverseEnumeratei}{-2}}.,
}

\setlist[enumerate]{font=\color{red}}
\setlist[ReverseEnumerate]{font=\color{blue}}% <----  What I am looking for

\begin{document}

\section{Enumerate list}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Last item
\end{enumerate}

\section{ReverseEnumerate List}

\begin{ReverseEnumerate}[start=3]
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Last item
\end{ReverseEnumerate}

\noindent
Second ReverseEnumerate:
\begin{ReverseEnumerate}[start=4, font=\color{orange}]
    \item Zeroth item
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Last item
\end{ReverseEnumerate}
\end{document}
```

#### Code: `Automated Version`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newlist{ReverseEnumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[ReverseEnumerate]{
    %% Following is to handle first run when the csuse{} is not defined
    start={\numexpr\csuse{@ReverseEnumerateStart \EnumitemId}+0},
    label={\arabic*\addtocounter{ReverseEnumeratei}{-2}}.,
    after={% Save for next run so we know where to start
        \pgfmathparse{%
            int(
                \csuse{@ReverseEnumerateStart \EnumitemId}
                -\arabic{ReverseEnumeratei}-1%
            )
        }%
        \edef\@temp{%
            \noexpand\AtEndDocument{%
                \noexpand\immediate\noexpand\write\noexpand\@auxout{%
                    \noexpand\csgdef%
                        {@ReverseEnumerateStart \EnumitemId}%
                        {\pgfmathresult}%
                }%
            }%
        }%
        \@temp%
    },
}
\makeatother

\setlist[enumerate]{font=\color{red}}
\setlist*[ReverseEnumerate]{font=\color{blue}}% <-- What I am looking for

\begin{document}
\section{Enumerate list}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Last item
\end{enumerate}

\section{ReverseEnumerate List}

\begin{ReverseEnumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Last item
\end{ReverseEnumerate}

\noindent
Second ReverseEnumerate:
\begin{ReverseEnumerate}[font=\color{orange}]
    \item Zeroth item
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Last item
\end{ReverseEnumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Besides, your solution allows quickly setting up every parameter other than color. I am interested in solving the within-header statement to not have to customize every instance; I'll try to see if I can solve it. Meanwhile, using Simon Dispa's solution. Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: After further research it appears that you need to use `\setlist*[ReverseEnumerate]{<options>}` so that the new options are appended to the existing settings.  Have updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly  `\setlist[...` but it does the work.

[image: A]

Use `\definecolor{etaremune}{rgb}{0,1,0}` to choose a green color for  `etaremune`.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlist[enumerate]{font=\color{red}}

\definecolor{etaremune}{rgb}{0,1,0} % green for etaremune

% ************************************* added <<<<  
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\etaremune}
{\csname label\@enumctr\endcsname}
{\color{etaremune}\csname label\@enumctr\endcsname}
{}{}%
\makeatother
% *************************************

% What I am looking for
% \setlist[etaremune]{font=\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{enumerate list}
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First item
        \item Second item
        \item Last item
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \section{etaremune list}
    
    \begin{etaremune}
        \item Last item
        \item Second item
        \item First item
    \end{etaremune}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Plenty of things to learn from your answer! I will try to play with it for any other parameters. Many thanks!